# Pandas dataframe column "can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reformat a date column in a dataframe so that it can be turned to the format "yyy-mm-dd', the issue is that the format it comes in is not a datetime type object and has a trailing Z where there would normally be some other data, it looks like this "2021-10-27T10:59:00.000Z", the end goal is to merge two dataframes and then write to a csv file but it can't be done properly without the same date column formatting.

```
def getEarnings(symbol):
    earnHistory = si.get_earnings_history(symbol)
    eHDF =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(earnHistory)

    mask = (eHDF['startdatetime'] > '2018-1-1') & (eHDF['startdatetime'] < '2021-7-30')
    eHDF = eHDF.loc[mask].rename(columns = {'startdatetime':'Date'}).drop(columns=['ticker','companyshortname','startdatetimetype','timeZoneShortName','gmtOffsetMilliSeconds','quoteType'])

    return eHDF
```

current output

```
                        Date  epsestimate  epsactual  epssurprisepct
3   2021-10-27T10:59:00.000Z         1.22        NaN             NaN
```

wanted output

```
                       Date   epsestimate  epsactual  epssurprisepct
3                2021-10-27          1.22        NaN             NaN
```

this is not a duplicate question, I have already looked into .dt.date as a solution but like i said this is not a date time value, so if using

```
eHDF['Date'] = eHDF['Date'].dt.date
```

I will get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\financialPythonPractice\backTesting.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\financialPythonPractice\backTesting.py", line 66, in main
    print(getEarnings('AAPL'))
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\financialPythonPractice\backTesting.py", line 49, in getEarnings
    eHDF['Date'] = eHDF['Date'].dt.date
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5461, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 180, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\jmkre\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 494, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `eHDF['Date'] = eHDF['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.split('T')[0])` will work if all of them have that T character.

Comment: @Milan Yeah that's perfect, I actually just figured that out as soon as you commented, I also did it through a for loop before that

Comment: @Milan avoid apply/loops whenever possible: `eHDF['Date'].str.split('T').str[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your column to datetime first:

```
eHDF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(eHDF['Date'])
```

Then to format the date without time:

```
eHDF['Date'].dt.date
```

To extract the date only with strings (will not allow doing date comparisons):

```
eHDF['Date'].str.split('T').str[0]
```

*NB. actually the YYYY-MM-DD format enables to sort by string comparisons as the months/days are zero padded and in the order of most significant to least significant (year>month>day)*

Answer (score 0):

The date column is probably of type string.
You will first need to convert it to datetime objects.

```py
eHDF.loc[:, 'startdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(eHDF['startdatetime'])
```

Thereafter you can succesfully filter and call the `.dt` accessor

Comment: You can use directly `df[COL]`, no need for `df.loc[:, COL]` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
eHDF['Date'] = eHDF['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.split('T')[0])
```

or before putting earnHistory into a data frame

```
for i in range(len(earnHistory))
        earnHistory[i]['startdatetime'] = earnHistory[i]['startdatetime'][0:10]
```

Comment: That second option would be _much_ better as `eHDF['Date'] = eHDF['startdatetime'].str[0:10]`